# Changing the project's targeted framework

Tags: c#

I have made a winform project who's target framework is .Net framework 4.5

I want this project to be compatible with lower frameworks too, such as .Net 2 or .Net 3

Is it possible? If yes, then, are there any consequences? Please tell. I don't want any modifications in source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can downgrade your project using the Project Settings in Visual Studio.

However: all source should comply to .NET 2 or .NET 3, whatever platform you want to target. That means that if you use lambda expressions, LINQ, async/await, TPL for example, you can't use them any more, and you have to edit them out in order to get your source code compiling.

Just for the record, I wouldn't care too much any more for .NET 2 and 3 since since they [aren't supported any more by Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=.NET%20Framework&sort=PN). Only if you really need them in a business environment I would take the effort.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to change it to .NET 3 but few errors came regarding Thread class and something about Microsoft.CSharp. So I am keeping it to v4.5 Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change target to .Net 2.0 and remove the unsupported `using`-s like `Linq`.